# How to delay heavy rendering in Vue.js and Vuetify

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue.js 2 and Vuetify 2.6 and have a somewhat heavy form rendering to do in expansion panels. When clicking on the header of a panel, there is a small delay before the panel section opens, as it is first rendering I guess. The delay doesn't bother me much, but I'd like to instantly display a progress indicator while the initial rendering is happening. Problem is, the progress indicator only appears after the rendering is complete. The click event happens instantly though, as seen in the js console of the below snippet.

Is there a way to delay the panel section's rendering to first display the progress indicator? Surprisingly the UI isn't frozen while the rendering happens, so the progress indicator animation works.

I can't use the expansion panel "eager" option because I have many panels and loading everything at once takes too much time.

This code snippet illustrates the problem with an exaggerated example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    loading: false
  }),
  methods: {
    click() {
      console.log('click')
      this.loading = true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.6.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.4.4/dist/vuetify.min.css">


<v-app id="app">
  <template>
    <v-expansion-panels>
      <v-expansion-panel @click="click">
        <v-expansion-panel-header>
          <template v-slot:default="{ open }">
            <span>
              <v-progress-circular
                v-if="loading"
                indeterminate
                size="14"
                width="2"
                color="blue"
                class="d-inline-block"
              />
            </span>
            <span>Click me! opened: {{ open }}</span>
          </template>
        </v-expansion-panel-header>
        <v-expansion-panel-content>
          <v-text-field v-for="(item, i) in 1500" :key="i" />
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
  </template>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the effects of the `loading` flag change (including rendering the spinner and the panel contents) are occurring in the same macro tick.

One workaround is to split the effects into two groups: (1) toggle `loading` to render the spinner and to open the panel, and (2) toggle a new flag to render the panel contents. This enables moving the second effect group into the next macro tick:

1. Add a Boolean flag as a data property, and conditionally render the panel contents with that flag.
2. In the `click` handler, await a macro tick (i.e., await a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) with no timeout).
3. Toggle the flag from step 1 to render the panel contents.

```html
<script>
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    1️⃣
    loadTextfields: false,
  }),
  methods: {
    async click() {
      this.loading = true
      2️⃣
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r))
      3️⃣
      this.loadTextfields = true
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

```html
<v-expansion-panels>
  <v-expansion-panel @click="click">
    ⋮
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
                           1️⃣
      <template v-if="loadTextfields">
        <v-text-field v-for="(item, i) in 1500" :key="i"/>
      </template>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    loading: false,
    loadTextfields: false,
  }),
  methods: {
    async click() {
      console.log('click')
      this.loading = true
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r))
      this.loadTextfields = true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.6.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.4.4/dist/vuetify.min.css">


<v-app id="app">
  <template>
    <v-expansion-panels>
      <v-expansion-panel @click="click">
        <v-expansion-panel-header>
          <template v-slot:default="{ open }">
            <span>
              <v-progress-circular
                v-if="loading"
                indeterminate
                size="14"
                width="2"
                color="blue"
                class="d-inline-block"
              />
            </span>
            <span>Click me! opened: {{ open }}</span>
          </template>
        </v-expansion-panel-header>
        <v-expansion-panel-content>
          <template v-if="loadTextfields">
            <v-text-field v-for="(item, i) in 1500" :key="i"/>
          </template>
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
  </template>
</v-app>
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I had tried using $nextTick without success, but your solution works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: I've been encountering the same problem. Which end up using second flag on setTimeout succession. Tbh I am curious as to what affect such delay, It stopped the rendering process and in my case the parent component wont show unless all the child component finished rendering.